# Google Assistant quiz action in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

I would like to build a simple Google Assistant Action with Dialogflow that lets users answer 10 questions and give them the result at the end.

My concept:

- Ask 10 questions in total
- If the answer is YES -> add +1 to the
  counter
- If the answer is NO -> add nothing
- After 10 questions give a summary like "You answered 6 Questions with Yes.

Do I need to use the Firebase Cloud Function Fulfillment for that? Any feedback is really appreciated.

Comment: Yes. It would be better to use Cloud Function Fulfillment as you may want to store the counter in [userStorage](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/save-data) and then use it when you prompt the user about how many answers he has successfully answered. Also, writing cloud functions would make it easier for you to handle future enhancements or connect to database if required.

Comment: If you just want a quiz app, you can follow this link to generate a quiz chatbot without any coding... https://medium.com/@abhi007tyagi/google-assistant-app-in-5-min-d23f5c16ec44

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to use the Firebase Cloud Function Fulfillment to develop a function to get all the "yes" and "no", you can follow [this tutorial](https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-create-a-chatbot-using-dialogflow-enterprise-edition-and-dialogflow-api-v2-923f4a965176) and then change the Datastore insert part to count how many "yes" are.

Answer (score 0):

You are not obligated to use the Firebase Cloud. You can use your own external https API connection to your own server where you could host all of your questions and answers.

Though in fact using the Firebase Cloud is easier to start with!

I am very new to GoA and Dialogflow development but i read in the docuentation that there is some kind of read/write storage thing available.

Yesterday i found out about JOVO and they even work with MongoDB or some other minimal stoarge solution - i still have not found out hwo they mange to put that inside an action, but it looks promising.